# Link clickable but does nothing

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm working on a page with animated link. See [this page](http://www.inuwmidden.nl/websites/dpf/?page_id=7) 
The problem is in those blocks in the grid. When you hover over you can click on the link icon right down under. It's is linked to the specific post, but it does nothing. However I can right click on it and then open the page.

I tried several things like changing the z-index and position of the div's but I can't get it to work. Is this a CSS problem or could it be in the jQuery somewhere?

Thanks.

Comment: the page is showing this error `Failed to load resource http://127.0.0.1:10029/public/linkverifierhelper.js` are you missing any file??

Comment: Please provide your code... say that page is no longer available in a couple months, how will people know what the problem was?

Comment: A good way to provide your code is to recreate a working example on JSFiddle.  Doing that also sometimes helps you find the problem on your own.

Comment: Yes well.. the problem is that I've got no idea where the problem could be. But I will give it a go in a jsfiddle. @Paritosh I'm not sure where you see that error?

Comment: Google chrome - console

Comment: @Paritosh I think that's a problem on your end.  Do you get that error on any other sites, because it's not from the one that's linked here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `li` is catching events bubbled up from the link.  The plugin assumes that any click inside that `li` is "selecting" it.  That is evident by looking at the class list on the `li` before clicking:

```
item col3 posttype1 check-trio category-2 category-3 geen-categorie catergory-1 tag-1 tag-2 tag-3 tag-4 isotope-item
```

versus after

```
item col3 posttype1 check-trio category-2 category-3 geen-categorie catergory-1 tag-1 tag-2 tag-3 tag-4 isotope-item selected
```

Note the addition of the selected class at the end.

The jQuery plugin you're using is interpreting clicks on your *items* as a click to *select* that item.  You need to configure your particular plugin to either not intercept those clicks, or, if that isn't possible, to explicitly capture the link clicks yourself and handle it before it bubbles up to the plugin.

One way to do the latter would be (untested)

```
$(document).on('click', '.dpf-items .item a', function(event)
{
  // manually change location, because isotope is intercepting clicks
  location.href = $(this).attr('href');

  return false;
});
```

Make sure to wire the above before isotope is wired.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This could be the problem indeed, I tried to delete the jquery part before but with no succes. I'll check it out again. Thanks!